# Working around AWS Step Function Map concurrency limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a `Map` task in an AWS Step Function which executes 100-200 lambdas in parallel, each running for a few minutes, then collects the results. However, I'm running into throttling where not all lambdas are started for some time. The [relevant AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) says you may experience throttling with more than ~40 items, which is what I believe I'm running into.

Does anyone have any experience with working around this concurrency limitation? Can i have nested Maps, or could I bucket my tasks into several Maps I run in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up working around this 40 item limit by creating 10 copies of the `Map` task in a `Parallel`, and bucketing up the task information to split tasks between these 10 copies. This means I can now run ~400 tasks before running into throttling issues. My state machine looks something like this:

[image: state machine]

Comment: Presumably you have the same iterator for each `Map`?  If so how did you manage this?  I get the error `Every state can only be used in one graph`.

Answer (score 8):

Use nested state machine inside your map state, so you can have ~40 child state machines executing in parallel. Then inside each child state machine use a map state to process ~40 items in parallel.
This way you can reach processing ~1600 items in parallel.

But before reaching that you will reach AWS Step Functions Quotas:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing something similar by bucketing the jobs and using multiple maps in a Parallel.

Comment: I've run into this problem, and am instead turning my large map tasks into child synchronous express workflows. I wish AWS would include an option to handle this automatically under-the-hood

Answer (score 4):

AWS now offers a direct solution to this, called "distributed map state", announced at re:invent 2022 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-distributed.html

It allows you to perform 10,000 concurrent map state tasks. Under the hood, it runs them as child step function workflows, which can be specified to run as either standard or express workflows